# Windows Server 2008 performance issue dealing with page file

Tags: windows-server-2008, performance

If I changed Windows virtual directory size (set an initial size and an upper limit) and also change its location (change to drive D other than default drive C). I am wondering any performance impact?

I change the setting by select my computer -> properties -> advanced -> settings -> advanced -> virtual memory -> total page file size for virtual memory on all drives -> disable letting system automatic manage, and manually set another drive D and its upper limit.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably depend on what you set the size to as far as a performance hit goes.  I wouldn't change it without a good reason though; generally Windows does a pretty good job managing the page file size.

Comment: +1, Don't set the size (let Windows manage the size) unless you have a **really** good reason to do so.

Comment: Hi rybl, any performance impact if I use Drive D other than Drive C to manage page file?

Comment: Hi Chris, any performance impact if I use Drive D other than Drive C to manage page file?

Comment: I would say probably not unless Drive D is slower to begin with.  (ie. an IDE instead of a SATA)

Comment: Why using drive D is not suggested, and why using the same drive (as OS drive) is suggested? Do you have any document to prove?

Comment: I don't have any document to prove this, but I am almost sure that it will not make a difference.  If anything it will be a bit faster because it will not be reading/writing to the same disk as the OS.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate if you could find some documents when you have time. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Microsoft has always recommended putting the pagefile on a disk other than the OS disk. If you're going to manually set it make sure to set the min and max to the same size, otherwise the pagefile will become fragmented and may lead to performance problems. In most cases, setting the pagefile to be 1.5 to 2 times the size of physical RAM is recommended.

Comment: "Microsoft has always recommended putting the pagefile on a disk other than the OS disk" -- do you have any document to prove? :-)